# How to make a character automatically keep jump when an "if" statement is true?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've started learning Unity and made a small script for a 2d character to move and jump.

The script works, though the problem is, I've made it so the character can only jump when it is on the ground, though after it jumps and touches the ground again, I have to let go of the jump button and press it again to jump again. How can I make it so that I can hold the jump button and have the character automatically jump again when the "if" statement becomes true?

```
{

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;
    private float moveX;
    private float moveY;
    private bool isjumping;
    public float Jump;
    public GameObject sqaureee;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        moveY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (moveX * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isjumping == false)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Jump));
        }

    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isjumping = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isjumping = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this article [Difference between `GetKey` and `GetKeyDown`](https://riptutorial.com/unity3d/example/11765/reading-key-press-and-difference-between-getkey--getkeydown-and-getkeyup) can help you? Or just use `GetKey` instead of `GetKeyDown` if you want to keep doing something as long as key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I've found a solution and am going to leave it here if someone stumbles upon the same problem in the future.

Basically, rather than using Input.GetKeyDown, you just have to use Input.GetKey. That's it!

Now another mistake I realized I made was using AddForce to jump. with Input.GetKey, sometimes it runs the AddForce code multiple times since you are on the ground for multiple frames. I changed AddForce to rb.velocity = (blah blah blah) and now I get persistent jumps.

Good luck!

Edit: I just realized that Rafalon had the idea before me and posted it, I just didn't see it before posting this. Thank you!!

Comment: I've posted the answer I found, though it says I have to wait 2 days before I can accept it as the solution. If anyone has a better idea, I would love to hear it :)